# I'm trying to sum AMT on every transaction but only sum NETAMT when the GL account is not 1 of 4 accounts

Tags: sql

I need to sum AMOUNT as AMT on all transactions but when it's not 1 of 4 GL accounts, I need to sum AMOUNT as NETAMT and AMT. Amount is for total sales and net amount is less shipping and tax.

I've tried CASE and IF statements but can't get the correct output/

```
CASE WHEN RL.GLACCOUNT_ID = @GL1 THEN SUM(RL.AMOUNT) AS AMT
     WHEN RL.GLACCOUNT_ID = @GL2 THEN SUM(RL.AMOUNT) AS AMT
     WHEN RL.GLACCOUNT_ID = @GL3 THEN SUM(RL.AMOUNT) AS AMT
     WHEN RL.GLACCOUNT_ID = @GL4 THEN SUM(RL.AMOUNT) AS AMT
ELSE SUM(RL.AMOUNT) AS AMT, SUM(RL.AMOUNT) AS NETAMT
END;
```

I can get the AMT to add up but can't get the NETAMT.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl (since we do not have any test data)

```
SUM(RL.AMOUNT) AS AMT,
SUM(CASE WHEN RL.GLACCOUNT_ID = @GL1 THEN 0
         WHEN RL.GLACCOUNT_ID = @GL2 THEN 0
         WHEN RL.GLACCOUNT_ID = @GL3 THEN 0
         WHEN RL.GLACCOUNT_ID = @GL4 THEN 0
         ELSE RL.AMOUNT END) AS NETAMT
```